# Error: Main class could not be found or loaded

Tags: java, ubuntu, command-line

I am new to Java and I want to run a simple test-program on an Ubuntu server via the command line. "Hello World" worked well. 
But now I want to add jar-files to my test program. So I followed [this](https://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/compile-and-run-java-in-command-line-with-external-jars/) simple tutorial.

I created a file "MyTest.java" like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;

public class MyTest
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
            // Print Hello World!
            String x = "Hello World!";
            System.out.println(StringUtils.capitalize(x));
   }
}
```

Compiling the java-file with

```
 javac -cp jars/commons-lang3-3.7.jar MyTest.java
```

worked well without errors and a MyTest.class() file is generated. But when I want to run the test-program with

```
java -cp jars/commons-lang3-3.7.jar MyTest
```

I end up with the following Error:

```
Error: Main class MyTest could not be found or loaded
```

What am I missing? Why is the compiler successful but yet the program unable to be executed?

**EDIT:**

To make it clear: I do NOT want to build a jar file (at least not yet). I just want to build and run a simple java program referencing a jar-file i downloaded from the internet. Like described here: https://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/compile-and-run-java-in-command-line-with-external-jars/

Java Version:

```
> java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

JAVAC Version:

```
> javac -version
javac 1.8.0_151
```

Comment: you forgot the `.java` on second command

Comment: I'm guessing that class `MyTest` is not in JAR file `htmlunit-2.29.jar`. What IDE are you using? And what java version are you using?

Comment: @JoshKisb: Do i really need the .java ending in the second command when i want to execute? Makes no difference at all.

Comment: @Abra: Sorry, i used jar file commons-lang3-3.7.jar. And yes, MyTest is not in this jar. But StringUtils is in the jar, because of that i reference it.

Comment: You need to include the location of the directory containing file `MyTest.class` in the argument to the `-cp` option of the `java` command, as in `java -cp jars/commons-lang3-3.7.jar:path/to/directory/containing MyTest`

Comment: @Abra: Saved my day! `java -cp jars/commons-lang3-3.7.jar:. MyTest` worked. Make it an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to include the current directory.

```
java -cp jars/commons-lang3-3.7.jar:. MyTest
```

Thought that would happen automatically. But the dot at the end of the -cp argument was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify "MainClass" to the Manifest.mf

That should be in the last step of Eclipse Jar Export Wizard.

Tell me if you're on another IDE or using Maven, that changes the procedure.

Your current command should run successfully.

Comment: I do not use any IDE. I just want to build and run a java application on ubuntu command line. And additionally i want to reference a jar file aswell. I just want to follow these instructions: https://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/compile-and-run-java-in-command-line-with-external-jars/ Do i need a manifest? I thought everyting i need to do is the same as in the tutorial.

Comment: I think it's quite clear you need a Manifest. Tutorials aren't bible and can't be right when the program language itself complaints with a clear stacktrace aboutwhat it's needed.

Comment: Sorry, i have to ask again. I use a jar file commons-lang3-3.7.jar downloaded from the net. In this jar file a manifest is integrated. I just want to use this jar-file in my application. I do NOT want to build a jar file. Do i need a manifest even if i do not want to build a jar file? If so: How to create it? Or MUST i create a jar file if i want to integrate third party jar-files?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your way of act, anyways, can u provide the package declaration of your MyTest class?